# Why ssh-gen makes difference between PEM and PKCS8?

Tags: public-key, ssh, pkcs8

Correct me if I am wrong, but `PKCS8` is format to store private key info. It could be binary-enoded (`DER`) or Base64 encoded (`PEM`).

`man ssh-config`

```
-m key_format
             Specify a key format for the -i (import) or -e (export) conver‐
             sion options.  The supported key formats are: “RFC4716” (RFC
             4716/SSH2 public or private key), “PKCS8” (PEM PKCS8 public
             key) or “PEM” (PEM public key).  The default conversion format
             is “RFC4716”.
```

I am confused with "PKCS8 Public Key" (while `RFC-5208` is "Private-Key Information Syntax Specification Version") but I also can't understand what is "PEM public key" here? PKCS8 could be PEM or DER. What does it mean?

Comment: OpenSSH's terminology is seriously confus{ed,ing} here. What they call 'PKCS8' isn't PKCS#8 at all, but rather PEM encoding of the `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure defined by X.509 to handle multiple PKC algorithms, which is more conveniently available in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.7 with the details mostly in rfc3279. This format is ASN.1 based, as is 'PEM' which is PKCS#1 as you found, while rfc4716 is based on the XDR-like format used in SSH protocol.

Comment: I know this is old but how do i make sure convert it to the proper putty file or how do use keygen to create a file i can use with putty

Comment: @user86133: the only keyfile format used by the putty _program_ is PPK which OpenSSH does not support and in particular cannot create. But the putty _package_ also includes another program **puttygen which among other things can convert** PPK keyfiles from or to OpenSSH files. On Windows it's a GUI and just looking at the menu options should be obvious, or you can click on Help. On Unix it's commandline with a man page in the long-standard Unix way which you should read.

Answer (score 4):

Oh, I have found an answer. PEM here is `PKCS#1` (RSA) key. Not sure why `ssh-keygen` used this terminology.  And `PKCS#8` could be used for Public keys as well since `RFC-5958` which obsoletes `RFC-5208`. A very good article is https://tls.mbed.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem and this question is also good: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065304/what-is-the-differences-between-begin-rsa-private-key-and-begin-private-key

Here is `PKCS#1`(RSA):

```
[foo@bar ~]$ ssh-keygen -f .ssh/authorized_keys -e -m PEM
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEApPGAMzobORnBJdPD0VvBif0cBkRC1KgTi4rDmscp+4F8Ke6nE/jE
.....
rf/DnkvPoJPiRLBnyjmyWsQ0dWHnRbSZSwIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

And here is `PKCS#8`

```
[foo@bar ~]$ ssh-keygen -f .ssh/authorized_keys -e -m PKCS8
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEApPGAMzobORnBJdPD0VvB
...
yk/avnG/lceGqChXgjxcHEKQRJYZRTnqrf/DnkvPoJPiRLBnyjmyWsQ0dWHnRbSZ
SwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: rfc 5958 officially obsoletes 5208, but it is no longer PKCS#8 (or even compatible) and I don't know of anything that implements it. Whereas at least OpenSSL and Java JCE continue to use PKCS#8 -- only for private keys (although for RSA at least the private key representation includes the public key).